# WebPack Loader for ONNX models

Tags: webpack, loader, onnx

I have multiple `onnx` models, and I want to load them dynamically using webpack `file-loader` plugin.

##### webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
    rules: [
    /* File Loader*/
    {
        test: /\.(glb|onnx)$/i,
        use:
        [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options:
                {outputPath: 'assets/resource/'}
             }
        ]
    }]
}
```

But My `.onnx` files (located in the `src/assets/models/*.onnx`) are not copied dynamically to the `dest` folder,

can you please tell me how can I load the `onnx` models using the file-loader correctly? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by copying the whole directory using the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin):

```js
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

    plugins: [
        /* Copy Plugin */
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { 
                    from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/models'), 
                    to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/models/') 
                },
            ]
        }),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.onnx$/,
        type: 'asset/inline',
        generator: {
          dataUrl: content => content
        }
      },
    ],
  },
...
```

**index.js**

```js
import * as ort from 'onnxruntime-web';
import model from '../networks/neural-name.onnx';

const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create(
    new Uint8ClampedArray(model.data).buffer,
    {
      executionProviders: ['webgl'],
      graphOptimizationLevel: 'all',
      enableCpuMemArena: true,
      enableMemPattern: true,
      executionMode: 'parallel',
    },
);
```